# Ejabberd xml record types definition

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

The **Packet** atom stores the xmlelement records which are printed as below. Where the **records** of xmlelement is defined. Unable to find in the ejabberd source tree.

```
I(<0.12602.0>:my_module:47) : in_filter_packet: {xmlelement,"iq",
                                                 [{"type","get"},
                                                  {"id","purpled56e4316"}],
                                                 [{xmlelement,"ping",
                                                   [{"xmlns","urn:xmpp:ping"}],
                                                   []}]} 


I(<0.13000.0>:my_module:47) : in_filter_packet: {xmlelement,"message",
                                                 [{"type","chat"},
                                                  {"id","purple4e6f6c61"},
                                                  {"to","test2@ubuntu"}],
                                                 [{xmlelement,"active",
                                                   [{"xmlns",
                                                     "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"}],
                                                   []}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

`xmlelement` structure was used in old version of ejabberd (2.x). I believe you are trying to use modules or example code that have not been updated for latest version of ejabberd. ejabberd now use `xmlel` records.

As a reference, in ejabberd 2.x, the `xmlelement` were not a properly defined record, but just tuple of the form: `{xmlelement, Name, Attrs, Childrens}`. You do not need to refer to any record to process them, you can just process the tuple. A record is a sugar syntax on top of tuple.

Comment: I writing a module for ejabberd version 2.1.11. So i guess there is no record type defined in ejabberd version 2.1.11(unable to find after grepping in *.erl and *.hrl files). currently no plans to upgrade, might do after 3 months.

Comment: Update my answer: As a reference, in ejabberd 2.x, the `xmlelement` were not a properly defined record, but just tuple of the form: `{xmlelement, Name, Attrs, Childrens}`. You do not need to refer to any record to process them, you can just process the tuple. A record is a sugar syntax on top of tuple.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Is there a way to print the tuple to raw xml string ?